# R- Summarize every column using a dataframe of weights in dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

Say I have a data frame of numeric values and a second dataframe of numeric values that are weights that is built like this:

```
Monday <- c(1, 1, 10)
Tuesday <- c(1, 2, 3)
df <- data.frame(Monday, Tuesday)

Monday <- c(10, 10, 1)
Tuesday <- c(1, 1, 1)
df_weights <- data.frame(Monday, Tuesday)
```

How can I summarize each column of the first data frame using weighted mean with the corresponding column in the second data frame as a source of the values for the weights?

In addition, I would like both the mean and the weighted mean in a single dataframe, how could I summarize_all with two functions like so?

Answer (score 0):

Is it something like that?

```
library(dplyr)
library(Hmisc)
bind_cols(df,rename_all(df_weights,function(x) paste0(x,".wt"))) %>%
  summarise(Monday=wtd.mean(Monday,w=Monday.wt),
            Tuesday=wtd.mean(Tuesday,w=Tuesday.wt))

##    Monday Tuesday
##1 1.428571       2
```

Or possibly something more general without dplyr :

```
Map(function(x) wtd.mean(df[[x]],w=df_weights[[x]]),colnames(df))
## $Monday
## [1] 1.428571
## 
## $Tuesday
## [1] 2
```

Getting the mean and the weigthed mean together is a little more tricky but purrr can help to generalize the previous answer. I don't know if the structure of the result match your need :

```
purrr::map_dfr(colnames(df),
   function(x) list(column=x,
          mean=mean(df[[x]]),
          wmean=wtd.mean(df[[x]],w=df_weights[[x]])))

### A tibble: 2 x 3
##  column   mean wmean
##  <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>
##1 Monday      4  1.43
##2 Tuesday     2  2
```